# How do I attach an id to a ListViewItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listview, listviewitem

In my latest project, I have a `ListView` that is bound to an `ObservableCollection`. This `ObservableCollection` contains a number of objects of my class `SongData`:

```
public class SongData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
}
```

These objects are filled with data derived from a SQLite database, and the property `Id` contains the primary key for that record. Obviously, I don't want to show this id in my ListView. However, I do need this id when I handle a DoubleClick event on the ListView.

My current xaml code is:

```
<ListView Margin="12,41,12,12" Name="lvwOverview" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding SongCollection}" MouseDoubleClick="lvwOverview_MouseDoubleClick">
     <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="Title" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}"></GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="Artist" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Artist}"></GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Now, I would like to be able to get the id (for use with the database), when the user doubleclicks on a ListViewItem. Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var data = List.SelectedItem as SongData;
if (data != null)
    ...
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Weird that I didn't think of this myself :D

Answer (score 0):

In your double-click handler, you should be able to get a reference to the item that was double-clicked (or work your way to it).  That's the same SongData reference that was bound to.

Just because it wasn't shown doesn't mean that the property doesn't exist anymore.  It should be there ready and available for use.